# Replacing bath fan light heater - Existing Wire is (3) /2 cable

Tags: electrical, bathroom

Old fan light heater was on a triple switch where each function had its own switch. I am a amateur DIYer, have tried each and every way possible to wire it. I either get nothing or the switch is bypassed causing the fan to run continuously. Please Help![image: new ventilation fan diagram][image: wirey mess]

Comment: Can you include a picture of your switch box?

Comment: I'm thinking your not supposed to run three separate cables like that.

Comment: @Harper  brain fart on my part.... momentarily  thinking fan and light on same switch. But never neutral on bare one.  Happy Halloween Harper.

Comment: Can you live with fan and light coming on together?

Comment: @JACK no sorry, YOU were right.  3 cables with the power at the fan is wrong.  3 cables with power at the switch is the situation I endorse.

Comment: I agree with 3 cables + power at the switch being correct. The last few of these I have done with smurf tube and just ran THHN  easier than the larger horribly expensive 12/2/2 & ground.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 4 cables going into the switch box and the white wires are pigtailed together and there is a hot, black, connected to the common post,  then  connect your three white wires from the switch box to the three white wires from the fan unit. Then connect each switch wire to one of the wires from the fan unit. You can rearrange the switch locations in the switch box for your preference. Remember to shut off the power at the main panel before doing any work.

In the future, don't just try all different combinations to see what works. Sometimes things will work but can still kill you..... Take pictures and come back to this site for help before you start. There are some really smart people (not me) that will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you have the hot at the fan and then 2 more cables going to the switch? If so this was a code violation but I have seen it done before.
First,   Identify the feeder cable and mark it, next tie the neutral / white wire of the feeder to the fan, light and heater. 
Now you have 2 cables going to the switch box you have to figure out which is which mark them 1 & 2 or identify them so you know the difference. 
Next at the fan tie the hot supply to one of the switch cable’s whites and mark that white wire with black at each end (actually any color other than green, white or gray is ok). The white you just marked in the switch box goes to all 3 switches.

Now you have 2 black and 1 white left, Mark the white again I like red in this case because it will be a switched hot but black works, tie it to one of your switches and the other end to the light , fan or heat black

repeat for the other 2 black wires each to a switch then to the fan / heat. Last if you have grounds tie them together in the fan box and ground the switch to it’s green screw,

now you should be able to power it up and everything will work.

Again separate cables is not to code but I have seen this done and with the feeder in the ceiling this would work, if you have 4 cables at your switch box and no others we will need to start over.

Comment: 4 wires at the switch box would be ok 1 feed and each device has its own cable but I have seen 3 wires in the ceiling many times mostly in 50’s & 60’s era homes, I always thought it was strange to have the exhaust fan pulling all the heat out. But that was the only heat source in many of that eras homes.

Comment: Since the folly of separate cables is proportional to current, strive to have supply and heater-switched in the same cable.

Comment: That would make sense it would be helpful if the op came back and let us know where the power comes in at.